# Place string to X-Axis on Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a question for Matplotlib. I am quite new to Matplotlib and Python.

So I have a series of Dataframe being read from MySQL in the form of:

```
Date
28.03.2022
28.03.2022
...
```

I am trying to plot the date on the x-axis of my graph using matplotlib.

I have tried to write it as a string to convert it

```
date_string=str(df1['Date'])
date_string=date_string.replace('.','/')
date_string=date_string.replace('\n',' ')
days = date2num(datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%d/%m/%Y'))
```

ValueError: time data '0     28/03/2022 2     28/03/2022 4     28/03/2022 6     28/03/2022 8     28/03/2022 10    28/03/2022 12    28/03/2022 14    28/03/2022 16    28/03/2022 18    28/03/2022 20    28/03/2022 22    28/03/2022 24    28/03/2022 26    28/03/2022 28    28/03/2022 30    28/03/2022 32    28/03/2022 34    28/03/2022 36    28/03/2022 38    28/03/2022 40    28/03/2022 42    28/03/2022 44    28/03/2022 46    28/03/2022 48    28/03/2022 50    28/03/2022 52    28/03/2022 Name: Date, dtype: object' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y'

The original form when I only turn it into a string is as shown below:

```
0     28.03.2022
2     28.03.2022
4     28.03.2022
6     28.03.2022
8     28.03.2022
10    28.03.2022
12    28.03.2022
14    28.03.2022
16    28.03.2022
18    28.03.2022
20    28.03.2022
22    28.03.2022
24    28.03.2022
26    28.03.2022
28    28.03.2022
30    28.03.2022
32    28.03.2022
34    28.03.2022
36    28.03.2022
38    28.03.2022
40    28.03.2022
42    28.03.2022
44    28.03.2022
46    28.03.2022
48    28.03.2022
50    28.03.2022
52    28.03.2022
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: Try this: `df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'], format='%d.%m.%Y');days = mdates.date2num(df1['Date'])`

Comment: After I put into it, I got this error. AttributeError: 'numpy.datetime64' object has no attribute 'toordinal'

Comment: Your actual data may be different, but I was able to take the data in question as a data frame and run the following code to convert it to mdates. `import matplotlib.dates as mdates;import datetime;df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'], format='%d.%m.%Y');days = mdates.date2num(df1['Date'])`

Answer (score 0):

The `date_string` in your code contains all components of your dataframe `df1` (index + all rows of `'Date'` column) which doesn't match the specified date format. The optimal solution is given by r-beginners in the comments.